# Deploying a Java web application on WebLogic server

Tags: weblogic-10.x

I don't know much about JSP or Java web application and I have to make some front end changes to a website written in JSP. The first step is to run the site on my local machine. I have copied the whole folder from the repo which contains the WEB-INF folder and all the config files.

How do I get it running on my WebLogic Server ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Follow following steps:

1. Create a war file.
2. Go to WebLogic console. `http://localhost:port/console`
3. In the `Change Center` section of the console, click the `Lock and Edit` button to open the server instance for changes
4. Go to `Domain Structure > Deployments`
5. You will see a `Summary of Deployments`. Click on `Install` button.
6. Click on the link `upload your file(s)`. Browse to the location on your file system where the `.war` file was saved. Click the radio button next to the .war file and click `Next`.
7. Since this is an application, for the targeting style, make sure `Install this deployment as an application` is selected. Click `Next`.
8. Click `Next` again to accept the defaults in this next pane, then click `Finish`.
9. You will now get a summary list of the settings for the deployment. Click the `Save` button. If everything went ok, you will see a message in green that says `Settings updated successfully.`
10. Back in the Change Center section of the console, click the green `Activate Changes` button. The application has been 'prepared', but not yet deployed at this point.
11. Go to `Domain Structure > Deployments` again.
12. In the Summary of Deployments, find your application, check the box next to it and click the `Start` button. Select `Servicing all requests`. Click `Yes` to continue.
13. If the state of your deployment says `Active`, you have successfully deployed your Web application to Weblogic.

Comment: Ho to then access the application? What is the port number? Thanks

Comment: If you only have admin server, then it will be the ports configured for the admin. If you have a managed server, and target of your application is the managed server then it will be the ports configured for the managed server.

Comment: the status of the application turns to prepared .... i have tried to run the application multiable times but it return to prepared again ... what is the solution for such a case?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jdeveloper, then attach your weblogic server to jdeveloper and directly upload to the particular server by selecting from GUI of jdeveloper as soon as you do your changes in application.

It would be beneficial for you to debug and run application if you use jdeveloper with default integrated weblogic server in it.  If you are using standalone weblogic server and have a different IDE then  points in above answer are workable and well explained.